# User permission on document

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, permissions

I've a strange comportement in SP2013.
When a user add a document in a library. He is the only person that can see documents added.

Do you know which parameter could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the user checked in the documents? The documents he added might still be checked out to him.

Go to **Library settings** -> **Manage files which have no checked in version** to see these documents.

Answer (score -1):

User must check in document (and publish) it so other users can see and edit it.

Comment: How do you configure to force user to check in his document when he adds one?